# How to create a report with a different name each time by nunit2report?

Tags: nunit, report, nant

I use Nant genrate Nunit Report by nunit2report.

And everyday it build it will replace the old one.

How can I generate report with different like:

```
TestReport_0815.html
TestReport_0816.html
....
```

Here is my build file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="dotNet_Login" default="build" basedir=".">
  <property name="nant.settings.currentframework" value="net-4.0"/>

  <target name="build">
    <solution configuration="debug" solutionfile="Test_Login\Test_Login.sln" />
  </target>

  <target name="run" depends="build">
    <exec program="Nunit\NUnit-2.6.0.12051\bin\nunit-console.exe">
       <arg value="dotNet_Login\dotNet_Login\bin\debug\dotNet_Login.dll" />
    </exec>

    <nunit2report out="NUnitReport.html">
      <fileset>
        <includes name="TestResult.xml" />
      </fileset>
    </nunit2report>

    <echo message="NUnit report generated."/>
  </target>

</project>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
<tstamp property="revision" pattern="yyMMdd" />

<nunit2report out="TestReport_${revision}.html">
   ...
</nunit2report>
```

This will result in file names like this:

```
TestReport_120815.html
TestReport_120816.html
TestReport_120817.html
...
```

You can play with the [`<tstamp/>`](http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/latest/help/tasks/tstamp.html) task to get the output file name you'd like.

Comment: is it possible to add serial number after the time? like (TestReport_120816_1.html). i dont't know how to identify the reports genarated at the same time.

Comment: Before passing the string pattern to the `out` property of `nunit2report`, you can check for the file presence on disk, and while it is present, increment the index. It might be better to create a NAnt function in C# which will return a valid name for a test report.